# phandle identification in the converted device tree source file

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, device-tree

I have converted a dtb file to dts. While understanding the converted dts file, how we can check the phandle definition? For example, I have come across `phandle = <0x1e>;` and when I checked for `0x1e` in the dts file then it is there in different properties(say `resets = <0x04 0x1e>;`, `clocks = <0x04 0x01 0x1e 0x04 0x01 0x1f>;` etc...) of the nodes but not as a node name. How I can find the phandle node in the converted dts file.

Comment: You seem to have convoluted the definition & use of phandle. Study the DT specification doc. `phandle = <0x1e>;` is the  property definition that can be used by other nodes that need to refer to this node associated with this property. You, instead, seem to think it's a reference. That's backwards.

Comment: The original dts source that was used to build the dtb file won't have included explicit `phandle` properties. The compiler will automatically add `phandle` properties to nodes that are referred to by other nodes and will choose a unique value for the `phandle` property and the references to it. When looking at a dts that has been converted from a dtb file, it's not always obvious whether a u32 value in a property is a reference to a *phandle* or not. Hopefully, the meaning of the property value will be documented somewhere, or you can work it out by some other means.

Comment: @IanAbbott , Now I understood that phandle property value is used as numeric identifier for a node where it is defined. The phandle property value is unique in the devicetree. Can you please help (provide any links) to understand the last two statements of your explanation ("When looking at a dts that has been converted from a dtb file, it's not always obvious whether a u32 value in a property is a reference to a phandle or not. Hopefully, the meaning of the property value will be documented somewhere, or you can work it out by some other means.").

Comment: @RaviA A reference to a phandle is stored as a u32 value. There is no type information stored in the property to mark it as a reference to a phandle, so it just looks like any other u32 value. In the original dts source, the a reference to a phandle will be symbolic like this `<&foo>` so is easy to distinguish from other u32 values. In dts files decompiled from dtb files, that `<&foo>` will have been converted to a number like `<0x2a>` so is hard to distinguish from other u32 values.